# Efficiently iterate over vectors consistently c++

Tags: c++, vector, iteration, c++14

I have `n` vectors and I need to iterate over all of them consistently.

I mean that first I need to iterate over all elements of first vector then to iterate over all elements of second vector and so on.

I have task to compare all elements consistently including the last element of `k-1`'th vector and first element of `k`'th vector.

I know the solution where I first concatanete all this vectors in one big final vector and then iterate over final vector.
But it seems to me that this solution wastes a lot of memory and time.

Please help me to find more optimized solution. 
If it exists.

For example, with complexities: `O(1)` additional memory and `O(n)` time .

Comment: Where is your attempt? How are you storing your `vector`s (and why do you have so many)? And what are you trying to compare exactly? Also you seem to be using the word "consistently" wrong, at least I don't understand what inconsistencies you are trying to fix.

Comment: Do you need to find equal vectors? neponatno)

Comment: I try to find common solution. When there are `n` vectors and we need to iterate over then.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but it seems that you can simply iterate over the elements in the vectors using two nested loops - outer one for vectors and inner one for elements.

Comment: Vectors pass to function.

Comment: @Gusev Slava, Do you want to write a functions taking as an argument your vector and do some stuff with it?

Comment: @SmitYcyken One function takes a lot of vectors. Vectors store elements of one type.

Comment: @Gusev Slava, if it so, you need a variadic template function

Comment: Can you show us some code with the vectors you have, and the place you would use the "concatenated" vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use two nested loops.

In C++11 and later, simply do

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > vec;
 // some code that sets up the vectors in vec

for (auto &v : vec)     // iterate over the vectors in vec
{
     for (auto &e : v)   // iterate over the elements of v
     {
          //  do whatever is needed to element e
     }   
}
```

If need be, `v` and `e` may be `const` qualified (to indicate not changing the vectors or their elements).    The total number of iterations will be the number of elements of the contained vectors.   The additional memory usage will be (at any point in time in the inner loop) two sets of references - one set for controlling the inner loop and one for the outer loop (i.e. no copies of the vectors or elements themselves).

Before C++11, the above loops can be rewritten less verbosely using `for` loops that work with iterators rather than ranges;

```
for (std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator v(vec.begin()), vend(vec.end());
     v != vend; ++v)
{
     for (std::vector<int>::iterator e(v->begin()), eend(v->end());
            e != eend; ++e)
     {
          //  do whatever is needed to element *e
     }   
}
```

Note the need to dereference iterators in this form.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need something that can be iterated over, you probably want something like [`ranges::view::concat`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views)

> Given N source ranges, produce a result range that is the concatenation of all of them.

This doesn't copy any values, so is O(1) storage and O(1) time.

If the thing you need is *exactly* `std::vector<MyClass>`, then you are out of luck, you will have to populate a vector with all the values.